# IndexOutOfRange exception

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, file.readalllines

Why is this giving a `IndexOutOfRange` exception?

```
string[] achCheckStr = File.ReadAllLines("achievements.txt");

if (achCheckStr[0] == ach1_StillBurning) // this is where the exception occurs
{
    setAchievements(1);
}
if (achCheckStr[1] == ach2_Faster)
{
    setAchievements(2);
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that you are actually getting the contents of the file using the debugger?

Comment: add this: if(achCheckStr != null) before i(achCheckStr[0] == ....

Comment: Add a break point and verify that `achCheckStr` has data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

there mightbe no file exists with name `achievements.txt`.
this statement `string[] achCheckStr = File.ReadAllLines("achievements.txt");` might be returning `null`.

**Solution 1:** so before accessing any files please check whether file exists or not by using `File.Exists()` method.

**Problem 2:** there might be no lines in your text file.

**Solution 2:** before accessing the string array which contains lines please make sure that it is not empty by checking its `Length`

Try This:

```
if(File.Exists("achievements.txt"))
{
    string[] achCheckStr = File.ReadAllLines("achievements.txt");
    if(achCheckStr.Length > 0)
    {
        if (achCheckStr[0] == ach1_StillBurning) 
        {
            setAchievements(1);
        }
        if (achCheckStr[1] == ach2_Faster)
        {
            setAchievements(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is assuming that the `achCheckStr` array has at least 2 elements without first checking how many there are.  If the file exists & the contents are empty, `achCheckStr.Length` will be 0 and the `IndexOutOfRangeException` will be thrown exactly where it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing "achievements.txt"? It could be in the wrong place, so the code would not find it.

You can fully qualify the path or put the file within the bin directory where the .exe is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way

```
string[] achCheckStr = File.ReadAllLines("achievements.txt");
        if (achCheckStr != null && achCheckStr.Any())
        {

            if (achCheckStr[0] == ach1_StillBurning) // this is where the exception occurs
            {
                setAchievements(1);
            }
            if (achCheckStr[1] == ach2_Faster)
            {
                setAchievements(2);
            }
        }
```